# Dúvidas com Arrays em C#

Tags: c#, array, método

Boa noite, pessoal.
Sou iniciante em programação e tenho duas dúvidas:

1. Quando estancia-se um array do tipo double em C#, cada posição do array inicia-sem como null ou zero?
2. Existe algum método que retorne a última posição OCUPADA de um array?
   Por exemplo, tenho um array de n posições e quero inserir mais um elemento neste array em uma sequência ordenada, só que tal posição é desconhecida, ou seja, preciso saber de alguma forma a posição subsequente que está vazia.

Answer (score 7):

> Quando estancia-se um array do tipo double em C#, cada posição do array inicia-sem como null ou zero?

Com zero. [Aqui tem uma tabela com todos os valores padrão de variáveis do C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

> Existe algum método que retorne a última posição OCUPADA de um array?

Sim.

```
array.Length
```

Suponho `array` um *array* de qualquer tipo.

> Por exemplo, tenho um array de n posições e quero inserir mais um elemento neste array em uma sequência ordenada, só que tal posição é desconhecida, ou seja, preciso saber de alguma forma a posição subsequente que está vazia.

Pra inserir um elemento ao final do *array*, faça assim:

```
Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + 1);
array[array.Length - 1] = valordouble;
```

*arrays* não são boas estrutura dinâmicas. O melhor seria usar uma `List<double>`.